# Break out of a tkinter listbox

Tags: python, tkinter, escaping, break

I'm trying to bind escape to a tkinter listbox and when I hit escape, it still wants to run the apply function.

```
def body(self, master):
        self.e1 = tk.Listbox(master, selectmode=tk.SINGLE, height = 10, exportselection=0)

        for name in self.names:
            self.e1.insert(tk.END, str(name))


        self.selection = 0
        self.e1.select_set(self.selection)

        self.e1.bind("<Down>", self.OnEntryDown)
        self.e1.bind("<Up>", self.OnEntryUp)
        self.e1.bind("<Escape>", self.test)


        self.e1.pack()

        return self.e1

    def test(self, event):
        self.destroy()

    def OnEntryDown(self, event):
        #self.e1.yview_scroll(1,"units")
        if self.selection < self.e1.size()-1:
            self.e1.select_clear(self.selection)
            self.selection += 1
            self.e1.select_set(self.selection)

    def OnEntryUp(self, event): 
        if self.selection > 0:
            self.e1.select_clear(self.selection)
            self.selection -= 1
            self.e1.select_set(self.selection)

    def apply(self):
        self.file.returnSelection(self.e1.get(self.e1.curselection()))
```

Can I please have some insight on what I'm doing wrong? I don't get an error, but instead of breaking out of the box, it just calls the apply method.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `self.e1.destroy()` (or `self.e1.forget()`, if you want to be able to repack it later)?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, I did and it still tries to go to apply

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I put an if statement in the function I was trying to manipulate that if the variable manipulated was not none, continue. Otherwise, it did not execute the code and I was not thrown any errors